# How to make d3 scales proportional even if domains are different

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is the example data set:

```
var dataset = [
    {
        x: 0,
        y: 1.188
    },
    {
        x: 22,
        y: 0.822
    },
    {
        x: 72,
        y: 1.366
    },
    {
        x: 82,
        y: 1.163
    },
    {
        x: 111,
        y: 1.601
    }
];
```

So, what I desire, for example: Distance between 0.001 and 0.002 on Y scale to be equal in width/proportions to distance from 1 to 2 on X scale on chart.

I tried it with linear scales but couldn't achieve proportions. I don't know if there is some built in method for setting those things.

Here is an attempt:
http://jsbin.com/goxamemare/8/edit?js,output

So, if I get it correctly in order to have equal ticks regardless of domain I need to take at least two things into considoration:
1. How many values (steps like 0.001, 0.002 for Y scale or 1, 2, 3 for X scale) there are for X and Y respectfully
2. To set one dimension, let's say width of the chart

So, that way I can work out:

```
height : number of values on Y = width : number of values on X scale
```

Which gives for example:

```
height : 810 = 360px : 300
height = 810 * 1.2
height = 972px
```

And so I get proportional ticks between Y and X. Right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have the same scale in both x and y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703143/how-to-have-the-same-scale-in-both-x-and-y)

Comment: @thatOneGuy - That's OK, but how to use my domain with the solution proposed for that other question? Post author had limitation of chart dimensions and no mentioning of data set. I can have opposite situation. Dimensions are not so crucial for me but domain values are.

Comment: put together a working JSFiddle of your example and I can take a look. Difficult to understand what your problem is